# perl input from 2 text files to make one text file

Tags: perl, awk

I have one text file (fileA), approx 200 lines, each line with the format

```
afield1 afield2 afield3 afield4 afield5
```

and another text file (fileB), approx 300 lines, same format

```
bfield1 bfield2 bfield3 bfield4 bfield5
```

I want to create another text file, where if afield1 & bfield1 match, it writes a line like:

```
"some text" bfield4 "some text" afield3 "some text" afield1
```

I think this would be very easy to do in perl, or even awk, if I just knew how.  a simple shell script is proving very difficult.

Very grateful for any help received.

Thanks

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by this: "If the fields match, it would just skip the line."

Answer (score 1):

Well this might be even easier with some modules but since you seem to need something quick and dirty, here's what I can come up with. (this assumes that your file is delimited by commas. Change the delimiter in the split call if you're using something else.

```
open(my $fh1, "fileA.txt") or die $!;
open(my $fh2, "fileB.txt") or die $!;
open( my $out, ">outfile.txt") or die $!;
while( my $line = <$fh2> ) {
     chomp($line);
     my @columns_2 = split(/,/, $line);
     my $a_line = <$fh1>;
     my @columns_1 = split(/,/, $a_line);

     if( $columns_2[0] eq $columns_1[0] ) {
          print $out "text $columns_2[3] more text $columns_1[2] more text $columns_1[0]\n";
     }
}
close($fh1);
close($fh2);
close($out);
```

Comment: except doesn't work for me - hopefully I can debug - keep getting 
    Can't use an undefined value as filehandle reference at line 2

Comment: hmm ... what version of perl?

Comment: perl5 (5.0 patchlevel 5 subversion 3)

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next}($1 in a) {print "sometext "$4" some text blah"} ' file1 file2
```

give a more concrete example of your data file and your expected output next time.

Answer (score 1):

In Bash:

```
join <(sort fileA) <(sort fileB) | awk '{print $8, "some text", $3, "some text", $1}'
```

If you're not using Bash, you may need to pre-sort the files.

```
sort fileA > temp1
sort fileA > temp2
join temp1 temp2 | awk '{print $8, "some text", $3, "some text", $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on ghostdog74's answer

```
awk '
    # read file1 first
    FNR == NR {
        # store afield3 for later
        a[$1] = $3 
        next
    }
    ($1 in a) {
        # bfield1 == some afield1
        print "some text " $4 " some text " a[$1] " some text " $1
    } 
' file1 file2
```

Comment: thanks - supposing afield1 occurs only once, but bfield1 may occur a few times in fileB - and I only want to print the line on the first match?

Comment: @paul44, then `delete a[$1]` after the print statement